# surjectivity and group cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I'm learning serre's famous galois cohomology.  and on page 12 he gives 2 exercises.  it seems that I need the following fact in finite group cohomology:

$f: G_1 \rightarrow G_2 $ is surjective if and only if for any $G_2$ -module $A$,  the induced map $f*: H^1(G_2,  A) \rightarrow H^1(G_1, A)$ is injective on the cohomology level.

suppose $f$ surjective,  and from the definition of the induced $G_1$ module strucutre on $A$,  I obtain the injectivity of the cohomology. I try to prove the converse,  but met a problem.  I have to prove when $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and the restriction map on the level $H^1$ is injective for arbitray modules,  one has $H=G$.  can anyone give me some help?  is this a classical fact in group cohomology?  thanks!

Comment: Why not try the obvious straightforward way? To prove a map's injective, pick two elements from the domain, assume they have the same image and try to prove that the inputs have to be the same initially. Only requirements: understand what $f^*$ does, and what it means that two things are the same in cohomology.

Comment: oh thank u, now I understand that the one side is just the definition, but I have no idea with the opposite direction; how to get surjectivity from the injectivty in the $H^1$ level?  thank u very much for helping me!